# Using QScriptEngine to compute calculations

Tags: c++, qt, calculus

I'm creating a diagram modeling tool that connects `Items` to `Tasks`. Items have `Properties` (simple *name/value* relationships) and Tasks have `Formulas`. I intend to produce a UI for the users to write in a `QLineEdit` a *formula* using C++ syntax ( ie, `(property1 * property2)/property3`), and then output the result. Of course, the *formula* would have to be somehow parsed and computed to output the result.

My concern with this is if using [`QScriptEngine`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qscriptengine.html) is appropriate for this. I've [seen that it can be used](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4429) to perform calculations using `evaluate()`. Besides the 4 "regular" operations ( +, -, * and /), I only anticipate that probably `sqrt()` and `pow()` might be required - but apparently, `Math` is also usable inside the evaluation string.

Also, I need to store and recover these *formulas*, so I was considering handling them as `QStrings` for that purpose, as I will need to write/read them to/from files.

Do you think this is a good approach? What would you suggest as a good read for this type of objectives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this approach is good. I've used it for a similar task. Note that `QScriptEngine` uses JavaScript syntax, not C++ syntax. But JavaScript syntax is powerful and fulfills usual needs of user-defined formulas. It supports regular operators, math functions, brackets, local variables, etc.

You can store a formula in `QString`. If you need to execute the same formula multiple times, you should use `QScriptProgram` to compile a formula before executing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually, when I mentioned the storing process, I forgot to mention that the idea is to store the formula, and then recover it to be used in a potentially different context, ie, using the same example as in the question, but with different properties. Do you have any insight you can share for this scenario?

Comment: You can alter `engine->globalObject()`. Every property added to this object can be visible for all formulas running by this engine.